# Spring Boot Actuator is recording OPTIONS requests with dynamic parameter of URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

we are unsing Spring Boot 1.5.9 and we do provide metrics for Prometheus.

When we do receive OPTIONS requests the path parameter is not replaced. For GET Requests the parameter is replaced. The controller looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, path = "/claims/{token}")
@RestController
public class ClaimDetailController {

    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, params = "token")
    public ResponseEntity getDetail(@PathVariable(value = "token") final String token) {
      ...
    }
}
```

When calling actuator with endpoint "/prometheus" we get:

```
# HELP gauge_response_claims_clgrRFhIRlNDV3pJTXhXRG40dWlPWURrVTJnMU1nPT0 gauge_response_claims_clgrRFhIRlNDV3pJTXhXRG40dWlPWURrVTJnMU1nPT0
# TYPE gauge_response_claims_clgrRFhIRlNDV3pJTXhXRG40dWlPWURrVTJnMU1nPT0 gauge
gauge_response_claims_clgrRFhIRlNDV3pJTXhXRG40dWlPWURrVTJnMU1nPT0 5.0
# HELP gauge_response_claims_token gauge_response_claims_token
# TYPE gauge_response_claims_token gauge
gauge_response_claims_token 1502.0
```

The first one is from the OPTIONS request. The second one from the GET request.

So why is the token from the OPTIONS request not replaced? Can this be achived?
If not - is it possible to remove OPTIONS requests from the metrics?

And this is the /metrics output:

> counter.status.200.claims.clgrRFhIRlNDV3pJTXhXRG40dWlPWURrVTJnMU1nPT0  2
> counter.status.200.cloudfoundryapplication 4

Here are some dependencies used by us:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_spring_boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask here. subject talks about logs but I see no logs in this question whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Spring Boot Actuator is recording the request within it's metrics.

Comment: yes, but that's not related to logging. So you're worried about naming in metrics? also, are you sure if [simpleclient_spring_boot](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) is recording the metrics and not spring? and what does your options controller look like?

Comment: if your OPTIONS requests go to unmapped metrics, are they even mapped to any controller...

Comment: The OPTIONS requests are not mapped by me. I'm using the default Spring Mapping for this request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that updating Spring Boot to 1.5.22.RELEASE

results in an output for OPTIONS requests like this:

```
# HELP counter_status_200_unmapped counter_status_200_unmapped
# TYPE counter_status_200_unmapped gauge
counter_status_200_unmapped 5.0
```

It's not perfect but alle OPTIONS requests are collected into one metric and not each one in a seperate one.